# get_file_contents of zipped file

Tags: php, zip, unzip

I've got a ZIP file sitting on my server.  I want to unzip it and then save the completely file contents into just one variable.

I do NOT want to save the unzipped file on my server or on a visitor's computer.  I just need all of the contents of that zipped file stored in a variable that I can play around with and eventually show on the screen.  Every other solution I've found for this problem includes resaving the file in unzipped form.

How can I do this with get_file_contents, or any other function?

Comment: What have you tried? `$contents = get_file_contents('file.zip')` should do the trick

Comment: Have you looked into http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php ?

Comment: Andy, that gets the zipped file contents.  I want to get the unzipped file contents.

Comment: @aynber I've tried my best with the ZipArchive documentation but it's a little overwhelming.  I've figured out how to get it so I can read all the contents of all the FILE NAMES in a zip file.  But I can't seem to find anything to just put the unzipped file contents into a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply find out the file names within the ZIP Archive with PHPs ZipArchive for example. try this (*have not tested it but you should be able to get it to work*) :

```
$za = new ZipArchive(); 
$za->open('archive.zip');
$fileContents = array();

for( $i = 0; $i < $za->numFiles; $i++ ) { 

    $stat = $za->statIndex( $i ); 
    $fp = $z->getStream($stat['name']);
    if(!$fp) exit("failed\n");

    $contents = '';
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $contents .= fread($fp, 1000);
    }

    fclose($fp);

    $fileContents[$stat['name']] = $contents;
}
```

Once you know the names of the files within the Zip you can also use something like this:

```
$path = sprintf('zip://%s#%s', $zipArchive, $fileNameInZipArchive);
$fileData = file_get_contents($path);
```